# How can I store file names of a scpecific folder to an array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, filesystems

I want to store name of files of one specific folder to an array by using JavaScript, is it possible? 
I did this before using ASP, but I don't know how can I do this by JS,

Comment: I think this might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537424/get-a-list-of-all-folders-in-directory

Comment: I think this might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537424/get-a-list-of-all-folders-in-directory